# Connecting MS SQL DataBase To GODADDY host

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am new to uploading websites online, I have uploaded my website to Godaddy host and run perfectly but i don't know how to connect my MS Sql Data base and how to configure my connection string ! can any one help me or give me a tutorial of how doing this starting from a normal MS sql Database with normal connection string(Local DB and Local connection string) until uploading it online  ?

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to a sql server database on go daddy works the same way as connecting to any other Sql Server db from a .Net perspective. 
Log in to your go daddy account to get the connection string info. There's even code samples in there for how to configure your connection string.

Alos, here's a link about .net connection strings in general

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of using MS SQL is that you can use the SqlClient native libraries, which are faster than ODBC, etc.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class Demo {
    public DataTable ConnectAndQuery() {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=IP-GOES-HERE;Initial Catalog=YOUR-DATABASE-NAME-HERE;user id=DB-USER-HERE;password=DB-PASS-HERE;Connection Timeout=300");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TableName", cn);
        DataSet results = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(results);
        return results;
    }
 }
```

I usually store my connection strings in the web.config.  There's actually a specific section you can store them in, if you'd like.  Here's an example of that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2(v=vs.85).aspx